# Extjs radiogroup fieldLabel not displaying inside panel

Tags: extjs, radiobuttonlist

I am using `ExtJs 2.3.0.`

I have a `panel` and inside it a `radiogroup` as follows

```
var testPanel = {
          xtype: 'panel',  
          border: false,
          items: [ 
                    { fieldLabel: 'Please select ', 
                      xtype: 'radiogroup', 
                      id: 'id1', 
                      columns: 2, 
                      vertical: false
                    }
                 ],
                 items: [
                            { boxLabel: 'Yes', name: 'yes', inputValue: 'Yes', xtype: 'radio'},
                            { boxLabel: 'No', name: 'no', inputValue: 'No', xtype: 'radio' }
                        ]
         }
```

**The issue is-**
The fieldLabel 'Please select' of radioBox is not displaying. I am able to see 'Yes'/ 'No' radiobuttons.

When I change xtype of testPanel  to 'form', the label displays.
However, I can't use 'form' xtype. I want to use 'Panel' only.

Please let me know why the fieldLabel is not diaplying inside panel and any workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the individual radio buttons must be items of the radio group. Here, you've got the `items` keys that is duplicated in your config object, meaning you actually end up with 2 radios in your panel, but no radio group.

Then, simple panels do not have support for displaying labels. You must use a [form panel](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#) for that.

Finally, you probably want to give all the radio in the group the same `name`, so that `myForm.getForm().getValues()` returns something like `{myField: "Yes"}` (the value will be taken from `inputValue`).

So here's what you're trying to do:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.create({
    xtype: 'form', // notice the changed xtype
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    border: false,
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Please select ',
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        id: 'id1',
        columns: 2,
        vertical: false,
        // radio buttons must be children of the radio group
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Yes',
            // you probably want to give your radios the same name
            name: 'myField',
            inputValue: 'Yes'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'No',
            name: 'myField',
            inputValue: 'No'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Labels in RadioGroups seem to still be unsupported in 3.4 - is this noted in any documentation?

Comment: @MichaelP https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Component.html#Ext-Component-cfg-fieldLabel