# EXT JS cannot see fieldLabel property when placing components horizontally

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, combobox, extjs3

I am writing an EXT JS application that contains two combo boxes, each with its own `fieldLabel` property. I want to place these combo boxes next to each other horizontally. However when I try to do this the `fieldLabel` no longer appears.

This is the relevant code:

```
    var stationsPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: 10,
        id: windowId + "stationsPanel",
         defaultType: "combo",
         width : "100%",
         layout: "hbox",
         items: [{
             fieldLabel: "Start Station",
             id: "startstation",
             allowBlank: false
         },{
             xtype: "spacer",
             width: 50
         },{
             fieldLabel: "End Station",
             id: "endstation",
             allowBlank: false
         }]
     });
```

I have learned from reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084941/extjs-radiogroup-fieldlabel-not-displaying-inside-panel) that `Panel` containers don't support displaying `fieldLabel` properties. I therefore tried to render my components differently, using the EXT [Dynamic Forms](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/dynamic.html) example (Form 3). This displayed the `fieldLabel` values but the components but they were still rendered vertically. I also tried the suggestion on [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?96400-FormPanel-with-hbox-layout-does-not-display-field-labels-%28in-ExtJS-version-3.1.0%29) but neither of these solutions worked for me.

In light of the fiddle in the first comment following this question, which uses EXT JS 5.0.1, I'd like to clarify I'm using EXT JS 3.4.0.

Comment: Works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/eep

Comment: I should have clarified I'm using EXT 3.4.0. I ran your fiddle using this version and it didn't work. Sorry for not mentioning that. Updated my post.

Comment: do you get any error if using firebugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this as I see at the example link you provide above

```
var stationsPanel = new Ext.Panel({
  bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
  frame:true,
  id: "stationsPanel",
  layout:'column',
  width : 700,
  items: [{
     layout:'form',
     items:[{
         xtype:'combo',
         fieldLabel: "Start Station",
          id: "startstation",
         allowBlank: false 
     }]
   },{
      layout:'form',
      style: {marginLeft:'50px'},
      items:[{
        xtype:'combo',
        fieldLabel: "End Station",
        id: "endstation",
        allowBlank: false 
      }]
    }]
 });
```

I am not put the `windowId` for the test
this is tested and as the rules, this working. you can see the result at https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/efs/preview and the code you can see at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/efs or http://jsfiddle.net/kapasaja/zn7e04so/

hope this can help you

Comment: This worked for the most part but there is no longer space between the combo boxes even though the `spacer` is still there. I tried adding a margin but this caused the components to no longer be in line with each other.

Comment: The problem of there not being any space between the `ComboBox`components works now when I add a `columnWidth` property set to 0.5 before each non-spacer item. I therefore removed the second item that contained the `spacer`.

Comment: the answer already modified for the space between the combo, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

fieldLabel displays only for form panel.try with form panel layout hbox

Answer (score 0):

No need for spacer there, margin propety do the job for you:

```
var stationsPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    width: 600,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [
            {
                 xtype: 'combobox',
                 flex: 1,
                 margin: 20,
                 fieldLabel: 'Start Station',
                 allowBlank: false
            },
            {
                 xtype: 'combobox',
                 flex: 1,
                 margin: 20,
                 fieldLabel: 'End Station',
                 allowBlank: false
            }]
     });
```

easy cake ;)

Comment: When I do this I can't see the `ComboBox` components or `fieldLabel` values at all. In any case the `xtype` value should be 'combo' not 'combobox'

Comment: 'combobox' is a correct xtype that i tested and work with
your problem is not with your panel I guess as lots of people answers here are correct the problem is either with your panel width, a custom css or the container of the panel, double check that or post the container code/ screenshot the view, may be I can figure out what's preventing your combobox from displaying propely